# **ERROR! Callback called multiple times** JHipster version 7.3.1 (latest) having Error in Node

Tags: node.js, jhipster

I have used other versions of JHipster but that one in my mac is not working fine, I am trying to generate a simple gateway (no entities yet), and after executing:

```
$jhipster
```

Filling the application metadata, I just got:

**ERROR! Callback called multiple times**
Error [ERR_MULTIPLE_CALLBACK]: Callback called multiple times
at NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at onFinish (node:internal/streams/writable:667:37)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:526:9)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
code: 'ERR_MULTIPLE_CALLBACK'

Comment: Does it work if you use Node.js 14? We're not compatible with v16 yet. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/16744

Comment: Ah, awesome, thank you @MattRaible

Comment: @MattRaible, which specific version (14) do you recommend?

Comment: The node and npm versions to use are indicated in the pom.xml or build.gradle

Comment: Fantastic @GaëlMarziou, thanks!

Comment: For someone who has not yet generated a project, the answer can be found in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/generator-constants.js or locally where you installed the generator

Answer (score 3):

So, according to @MattRaible and @GaelMariou, when having the ERROR! Callback called multiple times when generating JHipter applications or entities, you should verify the Node JS version. That version is provided in pom.xml or build.gradle, however, I never found a reference of node version in pom.xml (I use maven).

It is not clear where to get the exact version, nevertheless there is this article that states the same problem using node.js version bigger than 14: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/16744.

Meaning you should keep your node.js in version 14 until they solve that issue. I changed to v14.18.1, and now it is working sharp.